# Error when storing a directory path in a variable to execute a command

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a batch file, I want to run an executable that is located in another folder, and use it on files in my current folder.

I can accomplish this by running `C:\directory\example\executable.exe --exampleparam examplefile`, but what I want to know if it's possible to do this if `C:\directory\example` is unknown and stored in a variable.

Example:

```
@set folder=C:\directory\example
%folder%\executable.exe --exampleparam examplefile
```

I couldn't get it to work like this, and wording this use case is a little weird and didn't find much relevant to it.

Here's my full code. It imports the content of 40-something MS Access databases, each contained in their own folder, into a MySQL database using [this program's](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php) command line.

```
@set settingsfolder="C:\Users\me\Documents\import"
@set mysqlfolder="C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\mysql\bin"
@set msa2mysfolder="C:\Program Files (x86)\Bullzip\MS Access to MySQL"
@set mdbfolder="C:\Users\me\Documents\dumps"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@for /D %%f in (%mdbfolder%\*) do @( 
    @set fname=%%~nf
    @set databaseid=!fname:~0,2!
    @set settings=%settingsfolder%\settings.ini
    @type NUL > !settings!
    @echo [MoveDB MSAccess to MySQL] >> !settings!
    @set importdirectory=%mdbfolder%\!fname!\db\database.mdb
    @IF EXIST !importdirectory! @(
        @echo   sourcefilename=!importdirectory! >> !settings!
        @IF !databaseid! == 001 ( type %settingsfolder%\db_init.ini >> !settings! ) ELSE ( type %settingsfolder%\db_append.ini >> !settings! )
        echo Importing !databaseid!...
        %msa2mysfolder%\msa2mys settings=!settings!, autorun
        %mysqlfolder%\mysql --user=root -e "set @dbid=!databaseid!;UPDATE data.table1 SET db_id = @dbid WHERE db_id IS NULL;UPDATE data.table2 SET db_id = @dbid WHERE db_id IS NULL;"
        echo !databaseid! finished
    )
)
```

The error I'm getting on each iteration is "Unknown database: \mysql"

It works fine if I use the quoted paths instead of variables.

Comment: Yes it's possible. What happened when you tried this? Are there spaces in the directory name? If so, you must use the syntax `"%folder%\executable.exe"`. Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Thanks, I posted my full code, I was using quotes. Does the executable name have to be included in the variable?

Comment: @pidgezero, I am suprised that nobody pointed this out.. All of the @ signs are MADNESS! Just `@echo off` once at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to enclose the full command in double-quotes, not just the directory path.

Here's the relevant code as you have it now:

```
set msa2mysfolder="C:\Program Files (x86)\Bullzip\MS Access to MySQL"
...
%msa2mysfolder%\msa2mys settings=!settings!, autorun
```

This evaluates to the command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bullzip\MS Access to MySQL"\msa2mys settings=!settings!, autorun
```

But `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bullzip\MS Access to MySQL"\msa2mys` isn't a valid command. Instead it should be `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bullzip\MS Access to MySQL\msa2mys"` (notice how the closing quote terminates the command).

So you need to change your code to this (and update your other SET statements accordingly):

```
set msa2mysfolder=C:\Program Files (x86)\Bullzip\MS Access to MySQL
...
"%msa2mysfolder%\msa2mys" settings=!settings!, autorun
```

---

You should generally avoid including the double-quotes in the `SET` statement. Waiting until actually executing the command is much better. Further, by not including the double-quotes in the SET statement, you leave open the option of combining or splitting directory paths stored in variables without having to worry about first removing double-quotes.

For example if you have the code:

```
SET MyFolder=C:\Parent folder\Child folder
SET MySubFolder=Grandchild 1
```

You can easily combine them with:

```
"%MyFolder%\%MySubFolder%"
```

Which evaluates to the valid path `"C:\Parent folder\Child folder\Grandchild 1"`. This is much harder to do when you included the quotes in the initial SET statements.

Answer (score 0):

This works quite well in my tests.

My guess is that you have a blank in your folder name,
so the batch file should rather look something like this:

```
set "folder=C:\Program Files (x86)\afolder"
"%folder%\executable.exe" params
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I posted the full code above - I was using quotes when setting variables.

Comment: Debug your script: If the error arrives on the call to mysql, replace `mysql` by `echo` to see what is happening.

Comment: @pidgezero, it's better to put the quotes as shown in this answer rather than having them in the variable values (like in your script), particularly when appending...